# Apache web server <Location> directive

Tags: apache, perl, location, webserver

When a request comes to server A, for some URLs I need to serve files from Server B.

I know I can get it done using the `<Location>` directive.

I tried using a Perl script handler but couldn't get it to work.

```
<Location />
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler HTTP::Dispatcher
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out ProxyPassReverse:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass        http://serverb.xyz/
  ProxyPassReverse http://serverb.xyz/
</Location>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html